# Kendo Datepicker - Duplicating day (Brazilian Time zone)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I found this wrong behaviour with Kendo DatePicker. It only ocurr when the PC is set to use Brazilian time zone (Brasilia only, not Fortaleza).
And the problem start on November 2018.
This is the timezone configuration - set to Brazilian

[image: This is the timezone configuration - set to Brazilian]

And this is how I see calendar November 3th, 2018 is duplicated

[image: And this is how I see calendar November 3th, 2018 is duplicated]

At the time I change timezone to Buenos Aires the calendar came back to normal

[image: Time zone configuration set to Bs As]
[image: Calendar working correctly]

This is my kendoUI calendar code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                            .Name("FinishDate")
                            .Start(CalendarView.Month)
                            .Depth(CalendarView.Month)
                            .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "datepickerFinishDate", @class = "masked-date kendoCalendar", @tabindex = 3, type = "text" }))
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide datepicker code and relevant view codes to reproduce your issue? I'm not sure it's a datepicker bug which only occurred for Brazilian timezone.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I updated my question adding the Datepicker code.